# jQuery UI Dialog minWidth expands dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am dynamically adding dialogs using JSON (hardcoded for the example). My problem is the dialog attribute 'minWidth' - 'minHeight' works fine. When I'm resizing the window and reach the set minWidth the dialog expands to over 1600px (minWidth:200).
Any solutions?

Code:

```
var fenster =
[
    {
        "title": "Window 1",
        "height": "500",
        "width": "500",
        "minheight": "100",
        "minwidth": "100",
        "inhalt": '<img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" />'
    },
    {
        "title": "Window 2",
        "height": "300",
        "width": "300",
        "minheight": "200",
        "minwidth": "210",
        "inhalt": '<img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" /><img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" />'
    },
    {
        "title": "Window 3",
        "height": "400",
        "width": "400",
        "minheight": "200",
        "minwidth": "200",
        "inhalt": '<img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" /><img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" /><img src="Images\\awesome.jpeg" />'
    }
];
        for (i = 0; i < fenster.length; i++) {
            var div1 = document.createElement("div");
            div1.innerHTML = ("<a class=\"modalClick" + i + "\" href=\"#\">Window" + i + "</a>");

            $('#body').append(div1);

            var div2 = document.createElement("div");
            div2.id = "mbox" + i;
            div2.style.display = "none";
            div2.innerHTML = fenster[i].inhalt;

            $('#body').append(div2);

            eval("$(function () {" +
                "$(('.modalClick'+" + i + ")).on('click', function(){createWindow(" + i + ");});" +
            "});"
            );
        }


        function createWindow(i) {
            var f = fenster[i];
            $(('#mbox' + i)).dialog({
                title: f.title,
                width: f.width,
                height: f.height,
                minHeight: f.minheight,
                minWidth: f.minwidth,
                stack: true,
                fluid: true
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing `minWidth` with `maxWidth`

Comment: Hm, but minHeight works as it should? I mean that you only can make it minimal 200px small and everything more than 200px. But if I resize it with the resizer and reach the 200px it sets the dialog to over 1600px.

Comment: Add both `minHeight: 200px` and `maxHeight: 1600px`

Comment: Still the problem is the width not height :) and sadly it didn't work, it just ignores the maxWidth, but even if it would work, it just would limit the unwanted expanding at reaching the minWidth to the maxWidth. In a jQuery UI Sandbox it does work whyever (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaoMWK).

Comment: Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MareEY?editors=001

Comment: It does work now, but I have no idea what's the difference to mine?

Comment: Just removed the quotes of the `height`, `width`, etc.

Comment: Oh now I see, so easy, but so impossible to find. Just wondering why minHeight worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92810/discussion-between-tushar-and-idragon).